# Why is pgrep/pkill so much slower than ps?

Tags: kernel, process, ps, pgrep

I would have thought that `pgrep` would be much faster than `ps -ef` yet the contrary is true - `pgrep` takes about 4x longer. But only on my laptop e.g.:

```
$ time { ps -ef |grep foobar; }
real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.023s
```

Compare with:

```
$ time pgrep foobar
real    0m0.215s
user    0m0.189s
sys 0m0.021s
```

... the times above are representative of a typical run.

Context:

This is on an Intel i7 laptop running linux kernel 5.6.19-200.fc31.x86_64

I have another machine (a server) running 5.7.9-100.fc31.x86_64 and it does the `pgrep` in about 10-12ms with roughly the same number of processes (~260).

Just weird.

I tried kernel 5.7.11 on this laptop and it made no difference - `pgrep` was still about 4 times slower than ps. Same result after I rebooted to 5.6.19. Same result from the console.

On my raspberry pi-3b+ (4 cores) with raspbian, `pgrep` is about twice the speed of ps!!!

My laptop has an Intel i7, 8-Gb, 4-cores with hyperthreading and about 270 processes running

The server is i5, 8-Gb, 4-core and about 265 processes running

The pi is 1-Gb, 4-core and about 133 processes running

**EDIT:** I upgraded to kernel-5.9.16-100.fc32 and now `pgrep` is only about 3x slower than ps!!

**EDIT2:** a bit more info. strace on pgrep gives this:

```
     0.000089 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/29/cmdline", O_RDONLY) = 4
     0.000071 read(4, "", 2047)         = 0
     0.000052 close(4)                  = 0
     0.503431 stat("/proc/30", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
     0.012402 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/30/status", O_RDONLY) = 4
     0.002080 read(4, "Name:\tmigration/4\nUmask:\t0000\nSt"..., 2048) = 967
     0.000078 close(4)                  = 0
```

... so there's quite a delay in getting info on that process. There's no detail under that process so I don't know what it's about

Comment: I'd start with checking which versions of pgrep you are using and try using the same version on every machine to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Hmm - a friend tested his debian system which had the same pgrep (procps-ng-3.3.16) and he didn't see this problem.

Comment: Note that `pgrep` is searching through a mush smaller input than `ps -ef`. Using `pgrep -f` would be a better comparison. Of course, this makes your observation even stranger...

Comment: Just timing 1 execution is not good. It allows for random influences to confuse the result. "Performance Analysis", which is what you're doing. Try 100 or more times. Use `/usr/bin/time`.

Comment: waltinator - as I mentioned, the timings are 'representative' - of course I did multiple runs.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think an authoritative answer can be given other than "it depends". The CPU architecture, the type of Unix system, the number of processes on the machine, etc. etc. will throw the results this way or that, especially when the execution times are in the millisecond range.